# Does the Cakechat Chatbot update itself on disk when queries to the network are made?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, training-data

I have an implementation of [Cakechat](https://github.com/lukalabs/cakechat). I would like to train it on-the-fly. Is this possible without edits?

I am making a custom compilation of a neural network.

```
from cakechat.api.response import get_response
print get_response(x)
```

I expect the network to update to-disk every query. There are no errors. The code works with changes.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. You will have to write that code yourself.